# Python: How to use Xpath in Selenium to select the closest neighbor element?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have a long list of tables from an HTML page. The following is just a fraction of the list.

```html
<ul id="exportContentTree" data-space-key="VAG" data-content-tree-src="/spaces/exportspacetree.action" data-content-tree-loaded="true">
<li class="content-tree-node">
   <ul class="content-tree-node-children">
      <li class="content-tree-node">
        <input type="hidden" name="contentToBeExcluded" value="">
        <input type="checkbox" name="contentToBeExported" class="exportContentTreeCheckbox" value="134258951" checked="checked">
        <label class="label" for="contentToBeExported">
          <a href="https://ewiki.abc.com/display/VAG/Getting+Started">Getting Started 
          </a>
        </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="content-tree-node-children">
    <li class="content-tree-node">
      <input type="hidden" name="contentToBeExcluded" value="">
      <input type="checkbox" name="contentToBeExported" class="exportContentTreeCheckbox" value="137464227" checked="checked">
      <label class="label" for="contentToBeExported">                    
        <a href="https://ewiki.abc.com/display/VAG/Queue+Management">Queue Management
        </a>
      </label>
   </li>
  </ul>
<ul class="content-tree-node-children">                    
    <li class="content-tree-node">
        <input type="hidden" name="contentToBeExcluded" value="179758339">
        <input type="checkbox" name="contentToBeExported" class="exportContentTreeCheckbox" value="179758339" checked="checked">
        <label class="label" for="contentToBeExported">                        
          <a href="https://ewiki.abc.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=179758339"># Archive #
          </a>
        </label>        
    </li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

I want to check whether the text inside the `<a>` tag inside the `<label>` tag starts with #, which indicates internal content. If so, then Selenium will not check the checkbox `<input type='checkbox'>`that is right above the  element.

In the code given above, in the ideal scenario, Selenium should check the checkbox for "Getting Started" and "Queue Management" but not for "# Archive #"

I used the following code so that I can Selenium can iterate through the list and check all the checkboxes.

```py
for topic in browser.find_elements_by_class_name('content-tree-node-children'):
        topic_checkboxes = topic.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="exportContentTree"]/li/*[@class="content-tree-node-children"]/li/*[@class="exportContentTreeCheckbox"]')
for checkbox in topic_checkboxes:
        checkbox.click()
```

I tried to add an if statement to the second for loop to check if the link text wrapped between a label starts with #, which does not work:

```py
for checkbox in topic_checkboxes:
  if checkbox.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="exportContentTree"]/li/*[@class="content-tree-node-children"]/li/*[@class="exportContentTreeCheckbox"]/following-sibling::label/*').text.startswith('#') == False:
    checkbox.click()
```

Can someone tell me where I did something wrong? Is it the Xpath expression or anything else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below xpath :

```
//ul[@class='content-tree-node-children']/descendant::label[@for='contentToBeExported']//a[not(starts-with(text(), '#'))]
```

will only select the `a` tag that does not have `#` in starts-with.

we are using `not()` and `starts-with()` in conjunction to avoid any anchor tag that has # as a starting text.

Comment: My logic is that if the tag does not have # to start with, then Selenium can click the checkbox.

Comment: you can try this xpath to click :- `//ul[@class='content-tree-node-children']/descendant::label[@for='contentToBeExported']//a[not(starts-with(text(), '#'))]/../preceding-sibling::input[@type='checkbox']`

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. A very good lesson I've learnt.